# CSS hide/show selector still shows text in code?

Tags: css

I thought:

```
.eventfuture
 {
  display: none !important;
 }
```

Which is a very simple CSS class, ought to completely hide the text?

I apply the above to a paragraph class:

```
<p class="eventfuture">Text Here ABC</p>
```

What happens is that "Text Here ABC" is 100% hidden on the client side of the browser (good) but still present in the source code (bad).

Is this normal behaviour? I am sure it is not.

I don't want "Text Here ABC" to be indexed by search engines hence why I would like it completely hidden.

Any ideas what it is that I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This is normal behaviour. CSS doesn't change what is sent to the browser from your webserver, only how its rendered.

Comment: If you don't want it indexed you need to prevent it from being sent at all, not just hide it by using a style. `display:none` means exactly that — "do not display this thing that is here" which doesn't change the fact that it exists (so why are you "sure it is not" normal behaviour?) Preventing it from being sent depends on your server-side technology; PHP would do it one way, node.js another way, Python some way else. or you could use Javascript to *add* it on the client (indexers don't run javascript) but WHY? If people don't see it and you don't want it indexed why even have it?

Comment: The source HTML is sent to the browser from the server. CSS does not change the source code, it instructs the browser on how the HTML should be rendered.  Javascript is the same, it makes no changes to the actual source, but can adjust the DOM.

Comment: One thing you could do is have your element empty `<p class="eventfuture"></p>` and populate it after the page has loaded via AJAX. No guarantees though this won't be indexed as crawlers are getting smarter these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is impossible by css. Both `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;` will be shown in the source code.

**However**, if you want that part of your source code not to be indexed by google you can use:

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
<div>Something here</div>
<!--googleon: index>
```

But still some articles say this works and some say it doesn't.

I have been looking for a 100% solution for a long time. Some say using jquery `.show()` and `.hide()` can help as well.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Hiding text is not a good practice if you need SEO. Google bots don't like hidden texts such as `display: none;` because they think you are hiding keyword content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any css would achieve what you're describing.

```
display: none
```

Just *visually* hides the element that it's styling.

If you want to remove the contents from the document you should use javascript and modify the text/innerhtml from there. An example would be:

```
document.getElementByClass("eventfuture")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

What `display: none;` does is not to hide the element from the DOM. It simply hides it from the user and search engines can still index it. Probably you should hide it from the server.
**EDIT**
To remove the element from the DOM entirely, this might be a fix:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#some-element');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

---

[Real code snippet](https://gomakethings.com/removing-an-element-from-the-dom-with-vanilla-js/)
[Check w3schools tutorial on display none](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Your `removeChild` would indeed remove it from the DOM, but indexing robots would already have seen it, and they tend not to run javascript anyway.

Comment: @StephenP, that's why I advised that the Op does the hiding from the server side, if its that necessary. But once stumble upon an article that said Googlebot might run JavaScript before a page is been indexed.

Comment: Good to know jayB, thanks, I hadn't seen that — do you have a link where I could read up on that?